Modelling a tennis match winner using set winning probabilities
Let's say there is a best of 3 sets tennis match about to begin. If you have the probabilities of each player/pair winning each set, you can work out the match winning percentages pretty easily.
Fairly intuitively, before a point has been played, the Set 1 and Set 2 winner probabilities will be (pretty much) identical. This is because no matter what happens in Set 1, Set 2 is going to be played.
However, Set 3 is different since it will only be played in the case where the match is tied 1-1 after 2 sets. Therefore the Set 3 win %s will not be the same as the chance of winning a one off set, it will be the chance of winning a set given that two sets have already been played, with each side winning one each.
Due to factors such as momentum, the %s in this case will most likely be different, or at least need to be calculated differently.
Now, I want to be able to work backwards from a Match Winner % and Set 1/2 Winner %, in order to work out what the Set 3 % should be.
For example, on a 3 set match I can see Bet365 have Team1 as 75% and Team2 as 25% to win the match. They also have Team1 as 72% and Team2 as 28% to win Set 1.
We can assume that Set 2 will have the same probabilities as Set 1. We can therefore work out what their implied Set 3 Winner %s are using these ones given.
It works out as Team1 55% and Team2 45% to win the 3rd Set.
My problem is that this cannot possibly be correct in practice. Yes, Set 3 should probably be closer, as we now have the added information that these two sides are unseparated after two sets, however this seems too much.
I would argue in fact that the initial Set 1 %s given are too close to the Match Winner, and should be closer to around 69% for Team1 (rough estimate). This would then allow for a Set 3 win % for Team1 of 65%, which seems much more reasonable.
So, my final question is, is it correct that Set 3 %s should be much closer to 50/50 due to factors such as momentum, or have Bet365 in this case quoted a Set 1 win % too high for Team1?

I view this as a flawed question because betting lines are not an accurate probability measure. Betting odds are just designed to make the books as much money as possible.

Are you assuming that each player has a fixed chance to win any set that is played?  If so, you can calculate a formula, which will be a cubic, that player 1 will win the match give their chance to win a set is $p$.  You can use the solution to a cubic equation to go the other way.  On the other hand, maybe one player is in much better shape than the other and their chance in a third set is higher than in the first two.

These are odds set by a company that makes money offering the chance to bet. They set those odds by looking at what people are betting along with other public or proprietary information they may have.
It makes no sense to ask for a mathematical answer to your "final question"

is it correct that Set 3 %s should be much closer to 50/50 due to
factors such as momentum, or have Bet365 in this case quoted a Set 1
win % too high for Team1?

If you think Bet365 has the odds wrong you can back your intuition by betting. (I do not recommend that.)
